# Enabling many textBoxes at the same time

Tags: c#, textbox

I have `10 textBoxes` in one form and I have a `checkBox`.

I would like this checkBox to control if the textBoxes are enabled or not. I know I can do it `textBox1.Enabled = true; textBox2.Enabled = true; etc` but is there any way to do it in `one line` or shorter?

Comment: Depends on tech, WPF is very easy to do binding. WinForms you could do `textBox1.Enabled = checkBox.Checked;` etc? You could assign a TAG to the controls that will be affected and then iterate the controls and say if TAG = "BoundToChecK" then Enabled = xyz?

Comment: There are many examples on how to do this but you should look up how to use the `Controls` in a `foreach` loop and make sure that you make a recursive call that enables or disables all the textboxes it's very simple

Comment: What kind of application is it? Wpf/winform/asp.net?

Comment: `ToggleTextBoxes()` <-  One line.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey that's one line...which wraps up the other 10 lines. I think the OP is looking for a solution which doesn't involve individually setting each textbox's disabled state.

Comment: My point is the question seems like code golf, not practical

Comment: @James - exactly. I'm looking for a solution which will do it automatically for all textBoxes at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line of Code as follows,

You place all the text boxes inside a group box or a panel.

```
Pnl.Enabled = Chk.Checked
```

Comment: `Pnl.Enabled = Chk.Checked;` ;)

Comment: +1 beat me to it. This is probably the cleanest way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to create an array of `TextBox`'s first, and then iterate over it.

```
var textBoxes = new TextBox[] { ... };

...

foreach(var tb in textBoxes)
{
    tb.Enabled = true;
}
```

But you asked for a solution "in one line or shorter". To do it in one line, you'd have to do this:

```
new [] { textBox1 ... }.ToList().ForEach(tb => tb.Enabled = true);
```

or

```
new [] { textBox1 ... }.AsParallel().ForAll(tb => tb.Enabled = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ToggleAllTextBoxControls()
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        if (c Is TextBox)
             c.Enabled = chkEnable.Checked;
}
```

This will iterate through all controls on the form and enable it if it's a TextBox and the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cntrlCollections = GetAll(this,typeof(TextBox));

foreach (Control ctrl in cntrlCollections)
{
  ctrl.Enabled = checkBox.Checked;
}
```

Comment: Why the 2nd check if you only select TextBoxes in the first line?

Comment: That's true.. I could remove the but remember it's always better to not assume.. This also will only work if you are using native .NET controls and not 3rd party controls like Telerik controls for example but the OP should get the gist of what the code is doing here..

Answer (score 0):

More code golf (it's technically *one* line):  **Assumes the TextBoxes are directly contained by the Form**

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        checkBox1.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => { foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) { tb.Enabled = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked; } };
    }
```